# How to merge POJO instances in Groovy?

Tags: reflection, groovy, pojo

Given two POJO classes like these:

```
class UserA {
    String name
    String surname
    Integer age
}

class UserB {
    String name
    String surname
    String email
}
```

and relative instances:

```
usera = new UserA(name:'john', surname:'smith', age:20)
userb = new UserB(name:'mark', surname:'almond', email:'blah@gmail.com')
```

How can I merge "usera" and "userb" (usera <- userb) to get "usera" like this:

```
assert usera.name == 'mark'
assert usera.surname == 'almond'
assert usera.age == 20
assert usera.email == 'blah@gmail.com'
```

?

Generally I would like to add missing properties and values from other instances and overriding already existent properties' values in an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the properties from B to A using metaClass:

```
class UserA {
    String name
    String surname
    Integer age
}

class UserB {
    String name
    String surname
    String email
}

usera = new UserA(name:'john', surname:'smith', age:20)
userb = new UserB(name:'mark', surname:'almond', email:'blah@gmail.com')

userb.properties.each {
  usera.metaClass[it.key] = it.value
}


assert usera.name == 'mark'
assert usera.surname == 'almond'
assert usera.age == 20
assert usera.email == 'blah@gmail.com'
```